# jQuery place the button according to the height of the content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, jquery-selectors

I have the working demo is in this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kpatel/LpNMG/). The markup is something like this but it is only for first row. In the demo link I have given all the codes

```
<div id="content">
  <ul class="products">
    <li class="product pro first">
      <a href="#">
          <span class="onsale">Sale!</span>
        <img width="100" height="140" title="battlefield" alt="battlefield" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="http://web-vassets.ea.com/Assets/Resources/Image/FeaturedGame/battlefield-bad-company-2-thumb.png?cb=1340391602">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy </h3>
          <span class="price"><span class="strike-through"><span class="striked-text"><span class="amount">$&nbsp;67.00</span></span></span> <ins><span class="amount">$&nbsp;23.00</span></ins></span>
      </a>
        <a class="add_to_cart_button button product_type_simple" data-product_id="185" rel="nofollow" href="#">Add to cart</a>
    </li>

    <li class="product pro">
      <a href="#">
          <span class="onsale">Sale!</span>
        <img width="100" height="140" title="battlefield" alt="battlefield" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="http://web-vassets.ea.com/Assets/Resources/Image/FeaturedGame/battlefield-bad-company-2-thumb.png?cb=1340391602">
        <h3>Battle Field</h3>
          <span class="price"><span class="strike-through"><span class="striked-text"><span class="amount">$&nbsp;67.00</span></span></span> <ins><span class="amount">$&nbsp;23.00</span></ins></span>
      </a>
        <a class="add_to_cart_button button product_type_simple" data-product_id="185" rel="nofollow" href="#">Add to cart</a>
    </li>

    <li class="product pro last">
      <a href="#">
          <span class="onsale">Sale!</span>
        <img width="100" height="140" title="battlefield" alt="battlefield" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="http://web-vassets.ea.com/Assets/Resources/Image/FeaturedGame/battlefield-bad-company-2-thumb.png?cb=1340391602">
        <h3>Battle Field</h3>
          <span class="price"><span class="strike-through"><span class="striked-text"><span class="amount">$&nbsp;67.00</span></span></span> <ins><span class="amount">$&nbsp;23.00</span></ins></span>
      </a>
        <a class="add_to_cart_button button product_type_simple" data-product_id="185" rel="nofollow" href="#">Add to cart</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Here you can see one row has 3 column and another row has 3 columns. Now every content section has a add to cart button at the bottom of the page. Now I wanted to make all the buttons to keep at the bottom of my content and it will not mind whatever the length of text will be. To do that I just used some jQuery stuff here. Now in that demo you can see it is taking the maximum height of one element and setting the css according to it. But I want to keep that in every row. You can see in the first row there is ess content and in the second row there is more content. So in the second row it is okay to put the button at the bottom pare and it is taking the max height for that row.But in first there should be something like that. There it should check the max height content and should place the button according to that. So can someone tell me how to do that for every row? 
**Sorry to tell you that I can't change my markup. It will be remain the same**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in jQuery just use this

```
(function($) {
  function normalizeHeight(items) {
    var maxHeight = 0, itemHeight;

    items.each(function() {
      itemHeight = $(this).height();
      if (itemHeight > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = itemHeight;
      }
    }).height(maxHeight + 'px');
  }

  $(document).load(function(){
    var itemsPerRow = 3,
        items = $('ul.products li'),
        rows = items.length / itemsPerRow, 
        r, min, max;

    if (rows < 1) rows = 1;

    for(r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
      min = itemsPerRow * r,
      max = min + itemsPerRow;
      normalizeHeight(items.slice(min, max));
    }
  });
});</script>
```

This will make all the li's into equal height and it will check the tallest li in the row and make another i's in that roe to that height. Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows is dependent on the width of your browser window.  My window is wide enough that all of the items fit within a single row.

I'm trying to think of a way to target JUST the elements that share rows, without any actual rows existing.  There may be some way but it would be extraordinarily complicated.  The answer is to change the markup, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes but in my case I have 3 li's in a row. So what to do in that case?

Comment: as you can see in the markup the li has class last.And that class will be the last for in a row...